# Number of rounds for constant header size in common hashes and XOFs

Tags: hash, xof, optimization

We compute hash $H(M_0\mathbin\|M_1)$ of size $d\ge1$ for some constant header $M_0$ of size $m_0$, and $\nu\ge1$ messages $M_1$ of random content and size $m_1$.

For [Merkle-Damgård](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) hashes, a simple optimization pre-computes the first $\left\lfloor m_0/r\right\rfloor$ rounds (where $r$ is the block size), and for some minimum extra size $\mu$, the total number of rounds computed is
$$\text{rounds}=\left\lfloor\frac{m_0}r\right\rfloor+\nu\left\lceil\frac{\left(m_0\bmod r\right)+m_1+\mu}r\right\rceil$$
with, for some hashes:
$$\begin{array}{l|rrrl|rrrl}
\text{hash} & d&r&\mu&\text{(bits)}&\tilde d&\tilde r&\tilde \mu&\text{(bytes)}\\
\hline
\operatorname{SHA-256}    & 256 &  512 &  65 && 32 &  64 &  9 \\
\operatorname{SHA-512}    & 512 & 1024 & 129 && 64 & 128 & 17 \\
\end{array}$$

Note: The right side of the table assumes quantities are expressed in byte rather than bit. The only change to the formula is that variables get a tilde, except $\nu$.

**For more common hashes and XOFs¹, what are the corresponding formulas and parameters?**

I'm especially interested in common variants of SHA-3 (or KECCAK if it differs from SHA-3 other than by [value of padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72973/555)); SHAKE; various BLAKE; and perhaps some parallelizable hashes.

Update: I have changed notation several times to align with that in KECCAK/SHAKE for $r$ and output size $d$, and used greek letters in an attempt to avoid confusion with existing hash specifications.

---

¹ eXtendable Output Functions essentially are hashes where the output size $d$ is a parameter rather than fixed. An example is SHAKE256 of the [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Heading

\begin{array}{l|rrrl|rrrl}
\text{hash} & d&r&\mu&\text{(bits)}&\tilde d&\tilde r&\tilde 
 \mu&\text{(bytes)}\\
\hline
\operatorname{MD5}        & 128 &  512 &  65 && 16 &  64 &  9 \\
\operatorname{SHA-1}      & 160 &  512 &  65 && 20 &  64 &  9 \\
\operatorname{RIPEMD-160} & 160 &  512 &  65 && 20 &  64 &  9 \\
\operatorname{SHA-224}    & 224 &  512 &  65 && 28 &  64 &  9 \\
\operatorname{SHA-256}    & 256 &  512 &  65 && 32 &  64 &  9 \\
\hline
\operatorname{SHA-512/224}& 224 & 1024 & 129 && 28 & 128 & 17 \\
\operatorname{SHA-512/256}& 256 & 1024 & 129 && 32 & 128 & 17 \\
\operatorname{SHA-384}    & 384 & 1024 & 129 && 48 & 128 & 17 \\
\operatorname{SHA-512}    & 512 & 1024 & 129 && 64 & 128 & 17 \\
\hline
\operatorname{SHA3-224}  & 224 &  1152 &  4 && 28  & 144 &  1 \\
\operatorname{SHA3-256}  & 256 &  1088 &  4 && 32  & 136 &  1 \\
\operatorname{SHA3-384}  & 384 &   832 &  4 && 48  & 104 &  1 \\
\operatorname{SHA3-512}  & 512 &   576 &  4 && 54  & 72 &  1 \\
\hline
\operatorname{SHAKE-128} & d   &  1344 &  6 && \lceil d/8 \rceil & 168 &  1 \\
\operatorname{SHAKE-256} & d   &  1088 &  6 && \lceil d/8 \rceil & 136 &  1 \\
\hline
\operatorname{BLAKE2s-256}   & 256 &   512 & 0 && 32 & 64 &  0 \\
\operatorname{BLAKE2b-512}   & 512 &  1024 & 0 && 64 & 128 & 0  \\
\end{array}

---

### SHA3-x

[SHA3-x is defined with KECCAK](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) as;

1. $\operatorname{SHA3-224}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[448] (M \mathbin\| 01, 224)$
2. $\operatorname{SHA3-256}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[512] (M \mathbin\| 01, 256)$
3. $\operatorname{SHA3-384}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[768] (M \mathbin\| 01, 384)$
4. $\operatorname{SHA3-512}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[1024](M \mathbin\| 01, 512)$

**KECCAK**

and KECCAK defined as

- $\operatorname{KECCAK}[c] (N, d) = \operatorname{SPONGE}[\operatorname{KECCAK-p}[1600, 24], \operatorname{pad10*1}, 1600–c] (N, d)$

and note that $N = M\mathbin\|01$ and $d$ is the required output size, Now we have

1. $\operatorname{SHA3-224}(M) = \operatorname{SPONGE}[\operatorname{KECCAK-p}[1600, 24], \operatorname{pad10*1}, 1600–448] (N, 224)$
2. $\operatorname{SHA3-256}(M) = \operatorname{SPONGE}[\operatorname{KECCAK-p}[1600, 24], \operatorname{pad10*1}, 1600–512] (N, 256)$
3. $\operatorname{SHA3-384}(M) = \operatorname{SPONGE}[\operatorname{KECCAK-p}[1600, 24], \operatorname{pad10*1}, 1600–768] (N, 384)$
4. $\operatorname{SHA3-512}(M) = \operatorname{SPONGE}[\operatorname{KECCAK-p}[1600, 24], \operatorname{pad10*1}, 1600–1024] (N, 512)$

**Padding**

- $\operatorname{pad10*1}(x, m)$  is not important since the message is not formed yet.

**SPONGE**

- $\operatorname{SPONGE}[f, \operatorname{pad}, r](N, d)$

  1. Let $P=N \mathbin\| \operatorname{pad}(r, \operatorname{len}(N))$.
  2. Let $n=\lfloor\operatorname{len}(P)/r\rfloor$.
  3. Let $c=\lfloor b/r\rfloor$.
  4. Let $P_0, \ldots, P_{n-1}$ be the unique sequence of strings of length $r$ such that $P = P_0 \mathbin\| \ldots\mathbin\| P{n-1}$.
  5. Let $S=0^b$
  6. $\textbf{For } i \textbf{ from }0 \textbf{ to } n-1$

     $\textbf{let } S=f (S \oplus (P_i\mathbin\| 0c))$.
  7. ...

As we can see, we can precompute a message $M$ up to the maximum multiple of $r$  that is smaller than $\operatorname{len}(M)$. More mathematically $$\operatorname{precomputableLen} = \lfloor(\operatorname{len}(M)/r)\rfloor \cdot r.$$ And the $r$ for

1. $\operatorname{SHA3-224}(M)$ is $r = 1152$
2. $\operatorname{SHA3-256}(M)$ is $r = 1088$
3. $\operatorname{SHA3-384}(M)$ is $r = 832$
4. $\operatorname{SHA3-512}(M)$ is $r = 576$

and the formula

$$\text{rounds}=\left\lfloor\frac{m_0}r\right\rfloor+\nu\left\lceil\frac{\left(m_0\bmod r\right)+m_1+\mu }r\right\rceil$$

### SHAKE128 and SHAKE256

- $\operatorname{SHAKE128}(M, d) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[256] (M \mathbin\| 1111, d)$
- $\operatorname{SHAKE256}(M, d) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[512] (M \mathbin\| 1111, d)$

As we can see the main difference is the capacity and extra two bits appended to have the domain separation.

1. $\operatorname{SHAKE128}(M, d)$ is $r =1344$
2. $\operatorname{SHAKE256}(M, d)$ is $r =1088$

and the formula

$$\text{rounds}= \underbrace{\left\lfloor\frac{m_0}{r}\right\rfloor + \nu\left\lceil\frac{\left(m_0\bmod r\right)+m_1+\mu}r\right\rceil}_{\text{Absorbing part}} + \underbrace{\nu  \left\lceil \frac{d}{r} -1 \right\rceil  }_{\text{Squeezing part}}$$

### BLAKE2b and BLAKE2s

BLAKE2 uses modified ChaCha as compression function with 16 words. BLAKE2s is the 32-bit version so  $r=512$ here, and for BLAKE2b $r = 1024$ ( $s$ for small, $b$ for big).

and the formula

$$\text{rounds}=\left\lfloor\frac{m_0}r\right\rfloor+\nu\left\lceil\frac{\left(m_0\bmod r\right)+m_1+\mu } r\right\rceil$$

since BLAKE2 uses all-zero padding, they called it [minimal padding](https://www.blake2.net/blake2.pdf).

---

Comment: The padding of [KECCAK evolved](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72973/18298) during the competition.

Comment: Ah, so the difference in the Ethereum variant of SHA-3 would be "only" in the padding, and not other parameters. I imagined (baselessly) that the issue was with modified $c$ in the interest of speed, which existed at some point (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#Weakening_controversy)).

Comment: `BLAKE2 pads the last data block if and only if necessary, with null bytes. If the data
length is a multiple of the block length, no padding byte is added.`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice and hard work, I really like that table! Possible areas of polishing: "can precompute a message M".. That's $M_0$ in the question, and it has length $m_0$. Perhaps some indication in the first table that the "squeazing" of SHAKE is not accounted for [or adding that to the table, which might require putting the (bits) and (bytes) indication at more appropriate place, which I failed to do; if so, add reference to SHAKE formula]. For Blake2, perhaps replace formula with indication that $\mu=0$, or leave formula without $\mu$.